# Number of Unique sections in CDA schema

Tags: hl7, ccd, cda, c-cda

I have read CCD is a summarized version of CDA and has [17 unique sections](https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/ccd/) including the header. I couldn't find out how many overall sections there are when there are full-fledged CDA documents.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't necessarily a hard limit of 17 sections in a [C-CDA](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=492) 2.1 CCD. There are 17 sections listed for that document type, of which only 6 are required. But it's an open document template, so it's allowable to include other section types.

All sections use the same XML Schema elements. Section types are distinguished by the <code> and <templateId> elements.